# How to invoke the Iris endpoint in the sample-notebooks for Amazon SageMaker using SDK

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to invoke the endpoint from the `tensorflow_iris_dnn_classifier_using_estimators` provided in the sample notesbooks. In the sample, it invokes the endpoint using the same python object generated in the deployment process. In a large system, I need to know how to invoke this endpoint without this object and possibly in different languages. This is what I've tried:

```
import struct
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')

query = [6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5]
buf = struct.pack('%sf' % len(query), *query)

response = client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName='sagemaker-tensorflow-py2-cpu-2018-01-16-18-22-54-458',
    Body=buf
)
```

What are I doing wrong? I get the following error from cloudwatch:

```
[2018-01-16 19:51:21,091] ERROR in serving: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 0: invalid continuation byte
2018-01-16 19:51:21,091 ERROR - model server - 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 0: invalid continuation byte
10.32.0.2 - - [16/Jan/2018:19:51:21 +0000] "POST /invocations HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "-" "AHC/2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call the inference using the InvokeEndpoint in any of the languages that are supported by the AWS SDK for SageMaker.

The Python SDK is what you have in your example above, but a similar syntax can be done in java, JavaScript, .NET and others.

The call in the python API references (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sagemaker-runtime.html ) is

```
response = client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName='string',
    Body=b'bytes'|file,
    ContentType='string',
    Accept='string'
)
```

The Body should be encoded as the model knows how to read. I'm not sure why you decided to encode the way that you did, but you can try simpler options and use the b' prefix. The error message simply says that model was not eable to decode your Body input.

Comment: This is the generic way to call the endpoint in the API docs. How do I specifically do it for the iris endpoint? I don't understand the Body, ContentType and Accept in this case

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

with open('iris.csv', 'rb') as f:
    payload = f.read()

result = client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName='test-endpoint-iris',
    Body=payload,
    ContentType='text/csv',
    Accept='Accept'
)

print(result['Body'].read().decode())
```

Also make sure that your `iris.csv` does not contain the labels/header or remove them in your code.

Example data file for predictions:

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2
4.9,3,1.4,0.2
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2
5,3.6,1.4,0.2
```